# Clustering Psychometric Survey Data

Tags: clustering, hierarchical-clustering

I have created a 15 question survey to understand the financial preferences of people. It asks questions like-

> 'How comfortable are you making financial decisions?'

with generally 4 or 5 options like 'very comfortable', 'somewhat comfortable', ...., 'makes me anxious'.

I want to cluster this data to identify the groups of people with similar responses/behaviors. I have currently encoded users' responses as numbers with 'very comfortable' being encoded as 5 and so on.

I thought of doing Hierarchical Clustering but I am unsure if doing that on a Likert scale would make sense.

The goal is to cluster people with similar responses. How do I approach this?

Answer (score 1):

I would look to the literature for examples of (1) choice of algorithm, and (if distance-based) (2) choice of metric. For example, [Bland 2018](https://doi.apa.org/doiLanding?doi=10.1037%2Fcfp0000102) uses a clustering procedure in their psychometric model.